# Как заменить текст с помощью регулярных выражений?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Как заменить текст с помощью  выражений ?

Вместо `[img]ссылка[/img]`, заменить на `<img src="ссылка" style="max-width:100%;max-height:195px;z-index:92; top: 15px;"  alt="">`

**Вот текст:**

Сегодня была очень хорошая погода, небо было безоблачное [img]http://iconizer.net/files/Iconsland_Weather/thumb/128/Sunny.png[/img], был слышен легкий шелест листьев на ветру [img][http://ictютуе/files/thumb/128/Sunny2.png[/img]](http://ict%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B5/files/thumb/128/Sunny2.png[/img]). Безоблачное небо мне напоминало голубой топаз.

Интересуют варианты на **Jquery, JS** и php тоже не помешалобы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приблизительно так:

```
s = "Сегодня была очень хорошая погода, небо было безоблачное [img]http://iconizer.net/files/Iconsland_Weather/thumb/128/Sunny.png[/img], был слышен легкий шелест листьев на ветру [img]http://ictютуе/files/thumb/128/Sunny2.png[/img]. Безоблачное небо мне напоминало голубой топаз.";
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.textContent = s;
s = d.innerHTML.replace(/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/g, '<img src="$1" style="max-width:100%;max-height:195px;z-index:92; top: 15px;" alt="">')
```

Надо:

- нормально реализовать экранирование (не через создание div)
- подумать о некорректных bb-кодах
- подумать об экранировании в ссылках

Comment: Во!!! Супер !!!  Cпасибо!!!  остальное доработаю...

Comment: @gilo1212, дополнил.